# In case of prime ring $R$ , the set $ I = R_{12}R_{21} + R_{12} + R_{21} + R_{21}R_{12} $ is an ideal of the ring $R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring not necessarily with unity with an idempotent element $e\neq 0, 1$ induces the (two-sided) Peirce decomposition
$R = eRe ⊕ eR(1 − e) ⊕ (1− e)Re ⊕ (1 − e)R(1 − e)$. Here $eRe$ = $\{{ere | r ∈ R\}}$,
$eR(1 − e)$, $(1 − e)Re$ and $(1 − e)R(1 − e)$ are abelian subgroups of $R$, where the
abbreviated notation $eR(1 − e)$ stands formally for the set $\{{e(r − re) = er −
ere | r ∈ R\}}$; and similarly, $(1 − e)Re$ = $\{{re − ere | r ∈ R\}}$, $(1 − e)R(1 − e)$ =
$\{{r − er − re + ere | r ∈ R\}}$.

we call this idempotent element $e_1$=$e$ and formally set $e_2$ =
$1−e$. Then for $R_{ij}$ = $e_iRe_j$ (i, j = 1, 2) we may write $R$ in its Peirce decomposition
$R = R_{11} ⊕ R_{12} ⊕ R_{21} ⊕ R_{22}$.
However all these abelian subgroups are also subring but not ideal (proof is easy).

In case of prime ring$R$ , the set    $ I = R_{12}R_{21} + R_{12} + R_{21} + R_{21}R_{12} $ is an ideal of the ring $R$.

I want to know the following things,

1. How we define the $ R_{12}R_{21}$ and  $ R_{21}R_{12} $ ? As I found $R_{12}$ and $R_{21}$ are not ideals of the ring R.
2. How the set $I$ is an ideal in ring R ?

Comment: "Let R be a ring not necessarily with unity with an idempotent element e≠0,1" Do you mean 'not necessarily commutative'?  Because you immediately start talking about $1$.

Comment: Yes R need not be be commutative.

Comment: ........... why didn't you *immediately* correct the question?  Confirming the issue with me in a comment is definitely good, but then you should take steps to eliminate the problem...

Answer (score 2):

> How we define the $ R_{12}R_{21}$ and  $ R_{21}R_{12} $ ? As I found $R_{12}$ and $R_{21}$?

Why do you want to multiply two subsets of a ring? This is not usually done. But anyhow, defining it to be $e_2Re_1Re_2$ makes it an ideal in $R_{22}$, so that seems like a reasonable thing to use.

> How the set $I$ is an ideal in ring $R$ ?

It's straightforward to verify that when you write 
$$
I=\begin{bmatrix}eR(1-e)Re & eR(1-e)\\(1-e)Re& (1-e)ReR(1-e)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and

$$
R=\begin{bmatrix}eRe & eR(1-e)\\(1-e)Re& (1-e)R(1-e)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

that $I$ is left and right $R$ absorbing, and also an abelian group (that is the ring structure which is isomorphic to that of $R$.)

Comment: I don't see what "prime" has to do with anything.